# Kotlin combine lists based on common property

Tags: kotlin

I have two functions (GetPodsOne and GetPodsTwo) that return me a big csv string. I then do some processing to discard the part of the string I don't want. See snippet below.

```
var podValues = execGetPodsOne()
val testPodValuesLst: List<String> = podValues.split(",").map { it -> it.substringAfterLast("/") }         
testPodValuesLst.forEach { it ->  println("value from testPodList=$it")         }
    
podValues = execGetPodsTwo()
val sitPodValuesLst: List<String> = podValues.split(",").map { it -> it.substringAfterLast("/") }             
    sitPodValuesLst.forEach { it ->  println("value from sitPodList=$it")             }
```

This leaves me with two lists. See output of the above below:

```
value from testPodList=api-car-v1:0.0.118
value from testPodList=api-dog-v1:0.0.11
value from testPodList=api-plane-v1:0.0.36

value from sitPodList=api-car-v1:0.0.119
value from sitPodList=api-dog-v1:0.0.12
value from sitPodList=api-plane-v1:0.0.37
```

What i would like to do is end up with the objects inside a data class like below:

```
data class ImageVersions(val apiName: String, val testPodVersion: String, val sitPodVersion: String)

api-car-v1, 0.0.118, 0.0.119
api-dog-v1, 0.0.11, 0.0.12
api-plane-v1, 0.0.36, 0.0.37
```

I've used test and sit above but I'm going to have maybe another 5 environments eventually. Looking for a nice way to get the versions for each api and easily combine into that ImageVersions data class.

thanks

Comment: Do the api names of the two lists always match up in order? Can `sitPodValuesLst[0]` be "api-car-v1:0.0.118" but `testPodValuesLst[0]` be "api-plane-v1:0.0.36" for example?

Comment: No, it can’t be guaranteed the order will match and there may be entries in test that are not in sit too.

Comment: So if an entry is in test but not in sit, what do you want to happen to the result? Do you want the result to just include the test's version, or not include the entry at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that you're `going to have maybe another 5 environments eventually`, I tried to write something that will scale well:

```kotlin
enum class Env { Test, Sit }

data class ImageVersions(val apiName: String, val versions: Map<Env, String?>)

fun String.getNameAndVersion() = substringBefore(':') to substringAfter(':')

fun getVersions(envMap: Map<Env, List<String>>): List<ImageVersions> {
    val envApiNameMap = envMap.mapValues { it.value.associate(String::getNameAndVersion) }
    val allApiNames = envApiNameMap.flatMap { it.value.keys }.distinct()
    return allApiNames.map { apiName ->
        ImageVersions(apiName, envApiNameMap.mapValues { it.value[apiName] })
    }
}
```

[Playground example](https://pl.kotl.in/GBjmCKuPp)

- So instead of separate `val testPodVersion: String, val sitPodVersion: String`, here you have a map. Now the structure of `ImageVersions` always remains the same irrespective of how many environments you have.
- `getNameAndVersion` is a helper function to extract apiName and version from the original string.
- `getVersions` accepts a list of versions corresponding to each environment and returns a list of `ImageVersions`
- `envApiNameMap` is same as `envMap` just that the list is now a map of apiName and its version.
- `allApiNames` contains all the available apiNames from all environments.
- Then for every `apiName`, we take all the versions of that `apiName` from all the environments.

In future, if your have another environment, just add it in the `Env` enum and pass an extra map entry in the `envMap` of `getVersions`. You need not modify this function every time you have a new environment.

Comment: Actually i had a bit of a hiccup when i went to use it...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143292/kotlin-script-extension-method-is-a-member-and-an-extension-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
val testPodValuesMap = testPodValuesLst.associate { it.split(':').zipWithNext().single() }
val sitPodValuesMap = sitPodValuesLst.associate { it.split(':').zipWithNext().single() }

val mergedMap = (testPodValuesMap.keys + sitPodValuesMap.keys).associateWith { key ->
    testPodValuesMap.getValue(key) to sitPodValuesMap.getValue(key)
}

val imageVersions = mergedMap.map { (k, v) -> ImageVersions(k, v.first, v.second) }
println(imageVersions.joinToString("\n"))
```

which prints

```
ImageVersions(apiName=api-car-v1, testPodVersion=0.0.118, sitPodVersion=0.0.119)
ImageVersions(apiName=api-dog-v1, testPodVersion=0.0.11, sitPodVersion=0.0.12)
ImageVersions(apiName=api-plane-v1, testPodVersion=0.0.36, sitPodVersion=0.0.37)
```

Answer (score 1):

As a first step I would extract the *apiNames* from both lists:

```
val apiNames = list1.map { it.replace("value from ", "").split("[=:]".toRegex())[1] }
  .plus(list2.map { it.replace("value from ", "").split("[=:]".toRegex())[1] })
  .distinct()
```

Then I'd create the *ImageVersions* instances by looping over *apiNames*:

```
val result = apiNames
  .map { apiName ->
    ImageVersions(
      apiName,
      (list1.firstOrNull { it.contains(apiName) } ?: "").split(":")[1],
      (list2.firstOrNull { it.contains(apiName) } ?: "").split(":")[1]
    )
  }
  .toList()
```

The reason to first extract the *apiNames* is, that *apiNames* missing in one of the two lists will still end up in the final result.

[Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/mst88k8wv)

Comment: nice and simple