# Kotlin script - "extension method" is a member and an extension at the same time

Tags: kotlin

I have Kotlin some code that works as a class but when I try and run it as a Kotlin script I am getting " error: 'getNameAndVersion' is a member and an extension at the same time. References to such elements are not allowed"

```
enum class Env { Test, Sit }

data class ImageVersions(val apiName: String, val versions: Map<Env, String?>)

fun String.getNameAndVersion() = substringBefore(':') to substringAfter(':')

val testList = listOf("api-car-v1:0.0.118", "api-dog-v1:0.0.11", "api-plane-v1:0.0.36")
val sitList = listOf("api-car-v1:0.0.119", "api-plane-v1:0.0.37", "api-dog-v1:0.0.12")

getVersions(
    mapOf(
        Env.Test to testList,
        Env.Sit to sitList
    )
).forEach(::println)
    
fun getVersions(envMap: Map<Env, List<String>>): List<ImageVersions> {
    val envApiNameMap = envMap.mapValues { it.value.associate(String::getNameAndVersion) }
    val allApiNames = envApiNameMap.flatMap { it.value.keys }.distinct()
    return allApiNames.map { apiName ->
        ImageVersions(apiName, envApiNameMap.mapValues { it.value[apiName] })
    }
}
```

I don't think I'm doing anything wrong with the way I'm using the method reference but according to my compiler I'm wrong. Appreciate some help with this. thanks

```
kotlinc -script .\myscript.kts
error: 'getNameAndVersion' is a member and an extension at the same time. References to such elements are not allowed
```

Comment: I think this is because there is no 'top-level' in Kotlin scratch files, and _fun String.getNameAndVersion()_ is member of a 'hidden scratch file class'. I will gladly delete the comment if I'm totally off with my guess!

Comment: In a script you therefore have not other option than to use a lambda: _it1 -> it1.getNameAndVersion()_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any experience with scripts but this error occurs when you try to reference a function inside a class that is also an extension function. (Here it is pointing to `String::getNameAndVersion`). Maybe when you run a script, the entire code is wrapped inside a class and then executed.

To fix this you can do one of the following:

- Convert the function to a normal function which accepts a `String` parameter.

  ```kotlin
  fun getNameAndVersion(s: String) = s.substringBefore(':') to s.substringAfter(':')
  ```

  And replace `String::getNameAndVersion` with just `::getNameAndVersion` in `associate` function
- Other option is to directly call the function in the `associate`'s lambda instead of passing a reference of this function.

  ```kotlin
  .associate { it.getNameAndVersion() }
  ```